# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL while fetching Tweets from twitter

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, http-status-code-400

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


    public class Twitter{
    public static String getTwitterBearerTokenUrl() 
    {
        return "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Twitter");

    String base64Key  = null; 

    String Authorization = "Authorization";
    String BEARER = "Bearer";
    String UTF_CHARSET = "UTF-8";

    logger.info("Twitter::getBearerToken --> In");
    String AccessToken = null;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(); 

    base64Key = DatatypeConverter
                .printBase64Binary(("Customer_id"+":"+"Customer_secret")
                        .getBytes());
    logger.debug("base64Key: " +base64Key);

    URL twitterBearerTokenUrl;

    try {
            twitterBearerTokenUrl = new URL(getTwitterBearerTokenUrl());

        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Invalid Request  " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Request  " + e);
        }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    try{
    urlConnection=       (HttpURLConnection)twitterBearerTokenUrl.openConnection();

    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty(Authorization ,"Basic "+ base64Key);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset="
                            + UTF_CHARSET);

    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    urlConnection.getOutputStream());

    wr.writeBytes("grant_type=client_credentials");
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    InputStream inputstr =  urlConnection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader ireader = new InputStreamReader(inputstr);
    BufferedReader Reader1 =  new BufferedReader(ireader);

    String read;

    while ((read = Reader1.readLine()) != null) {

    System.out.println(read);
    buffer.append(read);
    }


        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Unable to connect with Twitter " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to connect with Twitter " + e);
        }
        AccessToken = buffer.toString();

        String[] tokens = AccessToken.split(",");

        for (String token : tokens) {
            String[] parts = token.split(":");
            if (parts.length != 2) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected auth response");
            } else {
                if (parts[0].equals("\"access_token\"")) {
                    parts[1] = parts[1].replace("\"", "");
                    parts[1] = parts[1].replace("}", "");
                    AccessToken = parts[1];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        logger.debug("accessToken: "+ AccessToken);
        logger.info("Twitter::getBearerToken --> Out");


        System.out.println("\nAccess token is : ----------> " + AccessToken+ "\n");
        String username ="SrBachchan";
        int count = 10;

        ArrayList<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();

        HttpsURLConnection getUrlConnection;
        getUrlConnection = null;
        URL geturl = null;      
        String url2 = null;

               url2 = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name="
                        + username +"&" + "count="+count;

                //url2 = url2.substring(0, (url2.length()-1));
                System.out.println("\nURL2 is :--->" + url2+"\n");
        try {

             geturl = new URL(url2);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Invalid Request  " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Request  " + e);
        }
        try {
            getUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)geturl.openConnection();

            getUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            getUrlConnection.setRequestProperty(Authorization, BEARER
                    + AccessToken);

            getUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset="
                            + UTF_CHARSET);

            getUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to request the process ");
        }
        DataOutputStream wr1 = new DataOutputStream(
                getUrlConnection.getOutputStream());

        wr1.writeBytes("grant_type=client_credentials");
        wr1.flush();
        wr1.close();

        System.out.println("*****************Before buffer*****************");
        BufferedReader reader;




        try {

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    getUrlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String read;
            while ((read = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        buffer.append(read);
            }
             System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=SrBachchan&count=10
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.aricent.oauth.Twitter.main(Twitter.java:206)
```

Context:
  I am trying to fetch the tweets of a specific user from twitter using the access token obtained from the code but it is throwing some https: bad request 400. I am not able to understand it as I am receiving the Access token properly but when I am using it to fetch the tweets then it is throwing the bad request exception.

Comment: Is this a [minimum working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: yes it is the minimal code i think so..please help if possible

Comment: Why not use the [scribe](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) library to implement the OAuth - which makes life dramatically easier (especially for OAuth1) - and actually you could use the same framework to make the actual authenticated request too? That would enable you to dramatically simplify this code.